# Web part search box filtering wrong/another web part

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, web-part, publishing-site, search-box

I'm running SP2013 Enterprise with SP1 with publishing enabled.

I have run into a very strange problem when creating a page containing two web parts refering to two document libraries.

When checking 'Display search box' under 'Miscellaneous' for the first web part (top or most left placed web part), the files in the second web part is for some reason filtered and not the files of the first web part. Doing the same for the second web part results in the expected behaviour of filtering the document library of the second web part. Same behaviour happens when I switch the order of the document libraries web parts around.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Edit: Somebody reported same issue: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FrKkCtzdzVU

Comment: It sounds like a bug that Microsoft still has not fix it yet.

Answer (score -1):

Install latest SP1 and run Windows update. This fixes the issue.

Comment: I have no way of testing if this is true anymore as I no longer have access to the solution, however I did have the latest SP1 installed and still experienced the problem. Whether a later windows update would have solved the problem I don't know. Can somebody else confirm this?